# Unzip a package in C# with .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, unzip

I need to access the content/folders in a zip package that has an extension other then zip (but the package is indeed a zip). Ideally I would like to just access the content from one of the subfolder without decompressing the package but I couldn't find a way to even unzip the package first. I have to use .Net 4 in c# so I don't have access to ZipFile.

I tried using GZipStream but I am getting an error message like this:
"The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a Gzip stream"

Answer (score 1):

Use SharpZipLib

http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/

http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/

It has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Its really easy to use.